Auto refresh Cloudflare cache
I have an API that runs on GCP behind Cloudflare. To optimize response time I want to cache requests responses using Cloudflare cache.
When a cached resource becomes stale, the subsequent request has to call the origin. I want to refresh the cache before the end of the TTL so resources are always served from cache, thus optimizing response time.
How can I achieve that ?
I've heard of stale-while-revalidate= in the cache-control Header, but even when I set it, the request that hit the cache when the resource is staled goes all the way to the origin, even if stale-while-updating is set.
I was expecting the request that hit a staled resource to hit the cache, be responded with the staled resource and then I was expecting Cloudflare to update the resource to serve subsequent requests with the fresh resource.
However it does not work like that and I was wondering if it can be achieved.

Try disabling Always Online to see if it resolves the issue.  If Always Online is enabled, then the stale-if-error and stale-while-revalidate and directives are ignored.

I finally found the documentation to achieve this:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/speed/optimization/content/prefetch-urls/
